# Confusion regarding potential energy of the "system"

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

Let's consider a block on a frictionless table. The block is connected to a fixed support on the table via a massless spring. Suppose the block is pulled aside by a distance x and then released. The potential energy of the "block+spring" system at the instant of release is taken to be 1/2 kx<sup>2</sup> (provided potential energy is zero at x=0).

I am aware of the following.

*If external forces do no work on the system and internal forces are conservative, the mechanical energy of the system remains constant.*

*The difference in potential energy corresponding to a conservative force is defined as negative of the work done by the force.*

Now, the forces internal to the "spring+block" system are:

1. Force by the spring on the block
2. Force by the block on the spring

Why isn't the potential energy corresponding to the force 2 is not taken into account while computing the potential energy of the entire "system"?
Is is that force 2 is nonconservative?

My question may seem wierd. But when the gravitational potential energy of a body+earth system is defined, both works (by the gravitational force of the body and by the gravitational force of the earth) are taken into account. Work due to gravitational force of body is dismissed only because of its small value.

Comment: You do  not count the potential energy twice. It is just $1/2\cdot x^2$ in this case (after all, the support is fixed)

Comment: But is not this the case in computation of gravitational potential energy of body+earth system? If it is there, why not here?

Comment: It is actually always the case. See my answer below that I just posted

Comment: "Spring potential energy" is defined for spring forces... The wall is fixed so you get the same situation as earth... You can define different potential energy for the force by the block on the spring (if it is conservative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not count the potential energy twice. It is always between a *pair* of particles/objects. How a change of the potential energy is distributed between the two bodies as a result of the work done depends on their masses. If you have one mass a lot larger, then the kinetic energy will practically only change for the smaller mass. For instance, if you drop an object with mass $m$ in the gravitational field of the Earth by a height $h$, this corresponds to a decrease of potential energy (and an increase of kinetic energy) of $\Delta U =mgh$, not $\Delta U =2mgh$ (where $g$ is the gravitational acceleration). The Earth will practically not gain any kinetic energy at all. Similarly, in your case (with the spring support fixed) the block will increase its kinetic energy by  $\Delta U =1/2\cdot kx^2$ not by $\Delta U =kx^2$. If you have two equal freely moving masses instead, they will share the potential energy between them, so each will only gain half the kinetic energy. It is always only the total kinetic energy change that is equal to the potential energy change.

I have illustrated this in the graphics below. The top half shows the case for the spring fixed to a wall ( or a very heavy free mass), the bottom half for the spring connecting two equal masses. In both cases the spring is stretched to length $x$ initially (for simplicity assuming the spring has zero extension when relaxed) with the masses at rest. The second picture in each case shows the spring contracted back to length $x/2$ with the masses having gained the corresponding kinetic energy, with the total energy (potential energy $U$ + kinetic energy $K$) equal to the initial (potential) energy $1/2\cdot k\cdot x^2$ (which is solely the elastic energy stored in the spring when stretched and is independent of the attached masses). The difference between the two cases here is merely that the kinetic energy imparted after contraction of the spring is shared between the two masses in the second case, because the work done on each mass is smaller due to the smaller distance each one moved.

[image: potential and kinetic energy of spring system]

Comment: I completely understood what you meant by "not counting twice". Note my comment on the response by @Farcher .

Comment: @KshitizKatiyar I'll add some illustrating graphics later today, which should help you to understand it better.

Comment: @KshitizKatiyar Please see my extended answer

Comment: *If you have two equal freely moving masses instead,they will share the potential energy between them* I beg to differ as there is no gravitational potential energy involved. The two masses that you mention do not store the potential energy pe as they do not change shape, form etc.The pe is stored by the spring which can be thought of as being made up of microscopic "masses" and bonds (springs) and the two masses at the ends of the spring exert forces on the spring which change the pe stored in the spring.The masses at the end are the parts of the system which has kinetic energy.

Comment: @Farcher The potential energy of the system depends solely on the extension of the spring. After the spring has contracted by some amount, the corresponding change in potential energy will be turned into kinetic energy of the attached masses (as the spring does work on them) according to the inverse ratio of their masses, so equally for identical masses.

Comment: @Thomas I read you statement as though the masses had potential energy but from what you wrote subsequently I realise what you meant was that the masses took the energy which was potential energy stored in the spring. Sorry.

Comment: @Farcher It doesn't really matter where the potential energy is stored. The only important point is that a force acts on the mass(es) and accelerates them. You can therefore say that the mass has initially potential energy and afterwards kinetic energy due to the work done. This is in fact  how potential energy is defined. But you can not say the *spring* has potential energy, because then it should also have kinetic energy, which is not possible as it is assumed massless. You should consider the spring rather as an anonymous entity (ie a kind of black box) that exerts a force on the mass(es)

Comment: @Thomas I am curious to know why we can't say the spring has potential energy. What does its mass have got to do with the possession of (potential) energy by it?

Comment: @KshitizKatiyar If a force is acting on a mass initially held fixed, it gains kinetic energy when released. In order to apply the concept of energy conservation, one just says then that the mass loses 'potential energy' by the same amount. This is just  for book-keeping to be able to have energy conservation. So 'potential energy' is just the negative of kinetic energy. But in this case, the spring is assumed massless, so its kinetic energy is zero, and you can therefore not say that it has potential energy either. You can only speak of the potential energy of the masses or the whole system.

Comment: @KshitizKatiyar The spring plays the same role here like for instance the gravitational force that makes two masses attract. The only objects that have kinetic and potential energy here are the two masses themselves. The gravitational force is just the mediator for changing one into the other.  In this case the spring is the mediator.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a force diagram of your horizontal spring-mass system and its surroundings.

[image]

The two sets of forces $F_{\rm s,b}$ and $F_{\rm b,s}$, and $F_{\rm s,te}$ and $F_{\rm te,s}$ are Newton third law pairs, ie equal in magnitude and opposite in direction.

Making the assumption that the mass of the table and Earth is much greater that the mass of the block we can then assume that the right hand end of the spring does not move.

In your system only the block can have kinetic energy because the spring has no mass, and only the spring can have potential energy as the block is assumed rigid and there are no other forces as a result of an interaction between the block and the spring.

Suppose the block and the left hand end of the spring move together by a small distance $\Delta x$ to the right.
The work done on the block by the spring is $F_{\rm b,s}\,\Delta x$ (which increases the blocks kinetic energy) and the work done on the spring by the block is $-F_{\rm s,b}\,\Delta x$ (which decreases the potential energy stored in the spring).
The net amount of work done by those two internal forces is zero but it has resulted in an increase in the kinetic energy of the block and a corresponding decrease in the potential energy of the spring with no change in the total mechanical energy of the spring-mass system.

Comment: "The work done on the block by the spring is b,sΔ (which increases the blocks kinetic energy) and the work done on the spring by the block is −s,bΔ (which decreases the potential energy stored in the spring)"... If we apply $W_{all forces} = \Delta KE$... the work done by internal forces explicitly cancel out and we get $\Delta KE$ = 0 . But clearly kinetic energy of block would be changed... Why the equation is telling lies?

Comment: Work done on the block by the spring = ΔKE of the system = - (Work done on the spring by the block) = - ΔPE of the system.

Comment: @KshitizKatiyar I was thinking of applying work energy theorem for the whole system, i believe it is not related to your question...

Comment: @Farcher it would be great if you can point error in my comment, I've been so restless since then

Comment: @PinkAura The block is not doing any work on the spring.  (after all it is assumned massless). The block has potential energy at the beginning and kinetic energy at the end. Its potential energy is turned into kinetic .energy. The spring does not come into it explicitly. It is implictly contained already in the spring constant $k$ in the expression for the potential energy of the block,

Comment: @Thomas Block does decrease/increase the potential energy of the spring, that's what the work done by the block.... block cannot have potential energy, it is rigid and that's what the Farcher's answer say and internal energy of block doesn't change.... If you just consider the block as a system, then there's no potential energy and work done by spring decreases the kinetic energy of the block, i'm having problem when you write work energy equation for the whole system

Comment: @Pink Aura You must understand that (Work done by the spring as it is compressed or extended through a certain distance) is equivalent to - (Work done on the spring during the compression or extension). -ΔPE is just a term used in place of the expression of either of these works. Read my previous comment again after considering this and your doubt will be resolved.

Comment: @Thomas I really don't see why you wrote that "block isn't doing any work on the spring".

Comment: @KshitizKatiyar I just wrote work-energy theorem, work done by all forces, and i did take all forces... that's what I did and there shouldn't be any problem in that.... there's a difference between equivalent to and equal to(at least as per my definition), if something is equivalent to, you can replace that quantity with other, work done by the spring is equivalent to change in potential energy... meanwhile, work done on the spring is equal to change in potential energy... suppose a force F is needed to elongate it, we can say work done by force F = change in potential energy of the spring

Comment: So it is better to say, Work done by the block on the spring= change in potential energy; Work done by the spring on the block = change in kinetic energy. Though if you add the two you would get the same result, but I was applying it simultaneously for the whole system...

Comment: @KshitizKatiyar https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152162/discussion-between-kshitiz-katiyar-and-pinkaura any further discussion can be done in chat

Comment: What must be emphasized is that ΔPE should not be counted twice.

Comment: @PinkAura You must see the illustrations accompanying the response by Thomas. You will see that the loss in potential energy in going from configuration 1 to configuration 2 is recovered as gain in potential energy.

Comment: 1/2 kx^2$ - 1/8 kx^2$ = (4 -1) / 8 kx^2$  = 3/8 kx^2$.

Comment: @PinkAura I didn't say that ΔPE is equivalent to the work done on the spring. Read carefully. I wrote that work done by the spring is equivalent to - (work done on the spring). What I meant is that potential energy of the spring can also be considered as "the energy stored in it against causing its elongation or compression". WE theorem in this situation has the form (work done by internal conservative forces) = (ΔKE of the system). The work on the LHS is accounted for by/ encapsulated in -(ΔPE of the system). Thus, we get -(ΔPE of the system) = (ΔKE of the system).

Answer (score 2):

Your system consists of three parts: the block, the spring and the table(if the table is nailed to the floor that would be the earth). The spring basically mediates the force between the table and the block, and because it is massless the total net force applied to it must be zero and it cannot have any kinetic energy. So, in the calculation of the mathematical construct that we call the potential energy of a massless spring, $\int F_{\text{net on spring}}.dx$, it won't have a contribution.

Your analogy actually holds here too, however, instead of the spring the other object would be the table (or the earth) which is assumed to be much heavier than the block.

Comment: I'm afraid I chose "block+spring" as the system. The choice of the system is independent of anything else.

Comment: So what is the net force on the spring? @KshitizKatiyar

Comment: The only external force on the spring is that by the wall.

Answer (score 0):

Since the spring is massless, the force by the block on spring does work which increases the potential energy due to change in the length of spring. The total potential energy of the system is the potential energy gained by the block when stretched or released which later gets converted to kinetic energy of block and spring. Hence, spring is massless, the kinetic energy of spring is zero which means the kinetic energy of the block.

Comment: Could you be clear?

Comment: how much more clarity do you need ? i explained it in simple terms ,where you did not understand it.

Comment: workdone due to force by the block on spring is taken as the increased potential energy of the block(also the spring's) ,which later converts to kinetic energy of the block+(spring=0)

Comment: Potential energy of the system is due to the individual contributions of potential energies corresponding to the internal forces of the system. Why is it that you just consider the work done by the force of the block on the spring (and compute potential energy) and not the work done by the force of the spring on block?

Comment: workdone by the force of the block on the string is while we strech it which is the gain in potential energy of the spring+block which later is converted to gain in kinetic energy of the spring+block,

Comment: I think a little more care is needed in your answer. You say "... potential energy gained by the block when stretched ...".   There are two things here that can cause confusion.  First, the block does not have potential energy, so it can't gain it.   Second, the block does not stretch, the spring does.   You get the first one right in your third comment, so why not in the text of the answer?

Comment: you are right ,the potential energy gained by the block+spring is nothing but the potential energy gained by spring as block cannot stretch but is assigned to block as its own potential energy .

Answer (score 0):

We *must* take account of both forces...

Once released...

The force of the spring on the block, acting through a displacement in the same direction as the force, gives the block kinetic energy.

The force of the block on the spring, acting in the opposite direction to the displacement of the end of the spring takes elastic potential energy away from the spring.